# How to append a list to another list in a python for loop when each element of the existing list is being changed inside the for loop?

Tags: python, list, numpy, append, extend

I am trying to write a code which will create modified lists in a for loop every time and append it to a new list. For this, I tried creating an empty numpy array with two elements which are to be modified inside the for loop iterating over dictionary elements.

```
r2 = []
r1 = np.empty(2, dtype = object)
r1 = r1.tolist()
r_1 = {'G':32,'H':3}
for i in r_1:
    r1[0] = i
    r1[1] = i + 'I'
    print(r1)    
    r2.append(r1)
print(r2)
```

which gives me `r2` as

`[['H', 'HI'], ['H', 'HI']]`

The `r1` values in each iteration are as expected. However, I am expecting `r2` to be

`[['G', 'GI'], ['H', 'HI']]`

I don't know why `append()` is not working properly. I also tried the same by doing `extend()` but the same thing happens on doing `extend([r1])` whereas on doing `extend(r1)` it gives me

`['G', 'GI','H', 'HI']`

Am I doing it wrong or the code is interpreting something else?

Comment: Maybe you want `r2.append(r1.copy())`

Comment: You have one list `r1` which you modify several times. Appending it to `r2` does not make a copy — it's still just a reference to a single list. You could move the code creating the list inside the loop to create more than one list.

Comment: @Mark Yes, that's a good solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you append `r1` twice to `r2` it essentially makes `r2` a list of `[r1, r1]` not the contents of `r1` when it was appended, so when `r1` is changed before the second append, the first element in `r2` which is a reference to `r1` is also changed.

One solution is to not use r1 at all and just append the contents directly:

```
r2 = []
r_1 = {'G':32,'H':3}
for i in r_1:
    r2.append([i, i+"I"])
print(r2)
```

A second solution is to append a copy of r1 to avoid the two elements having the same reference:

```
r2 = []
r_1 = {'G':32,'H':3}
r1 = [None, None]
for i in r_1:
    r1[0] = i
    r1[1] = i + "I"
    r2.append(r1.copy())
print(r2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem lies with the fact that you pass a pointer of r1 to r2. r1 is created outside the scope of the for loop but is changed inside the for loop. So, what r2 sees is 2 instances of r1 at its last state, which is ['H', 'HI'].

Try passing the subarray directly to r2 like `r2.append([i, i + 'I'])`

If you need a numpy array in r2, you can do `r2.append(np.array([i, i + 'I']))`